# to find memory occupied by individual application software in linux

Tags: memory-usage, memory-test

to find memory occupied by individual application running
 in linux.  actually i'm having a boot issue that is after installing an application Software so i want to see the memory occupied by that application. Ay one please help me

Comment: Please describe what boot problem you have, and which application you installed. The problem is probably not related to what memory it occupies

Comment: as my system is continuously rebooting every 1 minute the thing what i can see is only the LOGO and a .bp file has been installed in my system and after that this issue happened

Comment: yes it is a continuous version of the session  linux system rebooting automatically every 1 minute

Comment: [Edit] your question to add the requested information. Don't repeat that it reboots. Unless you add that information, it's not possible to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Install htop `sudo apt install htop` Then run it in a terminal.  It will tell you what each function is using for memory. This is one of many ways.  You can also install gnome-system-monitor `sudo apt install gnome-system-monitor` if you want a graphical display.  Both work pretty well.   Good luck.

Comment: As his system is stuck in a continuous boot loop, this is probably not feasible. Anyway, it's a prime example of [X-Y problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)

Comment: yep I didn't see that :(